# Nested loop logic for generating questions based on periods and brands resulting in incorrect iteration count

Tags: loops, asp.net-core, nested-loops

I need to establish a logic with nested loops in my project. My scenario is as follows; A company will add a ready-made question set. The question sets it adds depend on periods and brands. Since the 1st period may depend on more than one brand, the questions I added (statement b10) should be valid for each brand. I have 6 periods in total. It is necessary to produce 1440 questions in total with 240 questions in 6 periods. There is currently 1 brand here. My problem is that in the loops I set up, I get 10 times the result instead of 1440. The block where the error occurs starts from section B10 (where the questions are). Can you help me solve my problem?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> AddQuestions(int Type, int ItemID, int BrandID, Guid? ProjectGUID)
{   
    var projectQuestions = await _serviceManager.ProjectQuestions.GetAllAsync(a => a.ProjectID == project.ProjectID);

    var copyProjectQuestions = await _serviceManager.ProjectQuestions.GetAllAsync(a => a.ProjectID == ItemID);

    var ProjectMainTypeID = _serviceManager.Projects.GetProjectMainTypeID(project.ProjectID);

    foreach (var b0 in copyProjectQuestions.Where(a => a.QuestionLevel == 0))
    {
        ProjectQuestion newProjectQuestion0 = new()
        {
            ...
        };
        await _serviceManager.ProjectQuestions.AddAsync(newProjectQuestion0);
        await _serviceManager.SaveChangesAsync();

        foreach (var b1 in copyProjectQuestions.Where(a => a.QuestionLevel == 1 && a.ParentID == b0.ProjectQuestionID))
        {
            ProjectQuestion newProjectQuestion1 = new()
            {
                ...
            };
            await _serviceManager.ProjectQuestions.AddAsync(newProjectQuestion1);
            await _serviceManager.SaveChangesAsync();

            foreach (var b10 in copyProjectQuestions.Where(a => a.QuestionLevel == 10 && a.ParentID == b1.ProjectQuestionID)) //I think there is a logic error in this block
            {
                var Brands = await _serviceManager.Projects.GetProjectBrandsAsync(project.ProjectID, null);

                if (project.BrandQuestionModel == "Ayni")
                {
                    Brands = new List<ProjectBrand_Dto>() { new ProjectBrand_Dto() { BrandID = 0, BrandName = "Marka tanımı yok", isRival = false, isSelected = false } };
                }

                var projectPeriods = await _serviceManager.ProjectPeriods.GetAllAsync(a => a.ProjectID == project.ProjectID);

                foreach (var p in projectPeriods)
                {
                    foreach (var hh in Brands)
                    {
                        ProjectQuestion newProjectQuestion10 = new()
                        {
                            ...
                        };
                        await _serviceManager.ProjectQuestions.AddAsync(newProjectQuestion10);
                        await _serviceManager.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    await _serviceManager.Projects.UpdateAsync(project);
    await _serviceManager.SaveChangesAsync();
}
    return Json(myresult);
}
```

Comment: [Could you kindly check the sample code?](https://codeshare.io/78RKyr)